# Dolphin Emulator shows dots instead of characters in controller options, nowhere else

Tags: 18.04, display, fonts, emulation

I have installed Dolphin in other computers no problem, but when I went to install it here it did everything well. Except for when I wanted to change the controller setup:

[image: Don't worry about the language, it's Dutch, and has nothing to do with the problem]

(The language is Dutch, it has nothing to do with the error)

I have tried different Fonts, and re-installing the program.

Comment: Does the error occur if you switch your system's language to English?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Settings -> Region & Language

Comment: Yes, the problem persists